# Inverse image of basic open set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be morphism of schemes. Let $g\in A$ .

Is it true that $f^{-1}(D_{A}(g))= X_{f^{\#}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))(g)}$.

where, 
$X_{f^{\#}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))(g)}=[x\in X : (f^{\#}(\operatorname{Spec}(A))(g))_{x}\notin m_{x}]$

I am not able to establish any inclusion between the two sets.

Please help, I am badly stuck at this.

Edit : I got the solution. One needs to consider affine open subsets of $X$ and just use the definitions.

Comment: 1. What have you tried? Can you write down the definition of both sides? 2. A formatting tip: \operatorname{Spec} produces the correct formatting for $\operatorname{Spec}$, and I've updated your post with this.

Comment: I am using the definitions correctly but still the result is not coming unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for formatting tip.

Comment: If you can write down the definitions, please do so in your post! This is a great first step when you're "badly stuck", see for instance [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Including your work and understanding so far [adds context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) which makes this question better - more likely for you to get a good answer, less likely to be closed as a duplicate, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.