For a $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ -scheme $f: T\to X$, $\tilde{f^b_X} = f^b : \mathcal{O}_X \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_T$?
Let $X:=\operatorname{Spec}A$ be an affine scheme and $ (f,f^b) : T\to X$ be a $X$-scheme with $f^b: \mathcal{O}_X \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_T$.  Then we have an $A$-algebra $f^{b}_X : A \to \Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}_T)$. In the Gortz's, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Remark 7.18, the functor $B\to \tilde{B}$ induces an equivalence of the category of $A$-algebras with category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras. Then my question is, by this functor, $\tilde{f^b_X} = f^b ?$ In my first attempt, this statement is needed to prove that for each $A$-algebra $B$, the relatvie spectrum ( $X$-scheme ) $\operatorname{Spec} \tilde{B}$ ( Gortz's book p.290, Proposition 11.1 ) is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} B$ as $X$-scheme, by showing that each represent same functor. If needed, I will upload detailed process.
EDIT : I think I overlooked something. If my question is true, Then $\widetilde{\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)} = f_{*}\mathcal{O}_T .$ So $f_{*}\mathcal{O}_T$ is quasi-coherent, which maybe false unless $T$ is affine. Interlude question : Instead, directly, next statement is true?
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Spec}(A)}(T,\operatorname{Spec}(B))=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X-\textit{Alg}}(\tilde{B},f_*(\mathcal{O}_T)) \tag{1}$$
If so, then $\operatorname{Spec}(\tilde{B})$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ represent same functor $$(f: T\to X)  \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X-\textit{Alg}}(\tilde{B},f_{*}\mathcal{O}_T), $$
( C.f. Gortz's book Proposition 11.1 ) so that $\operatorname{Spec}(\tilde{B}) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(B)$. Can we really prove the $(1)$? If so, how?

Can I ask why that equivalence of categories is not enough?

O.K. I made an EDIT reflecting my misunderstanding. Can you see?

Ok I see. I think LHS on (1) is equal to maps of $A$-algebra from $B$ to global sections of $f_*\mathcal{O}_T$. I guess each map on global sections should determine whole sheaf map, so equal to RHS? (I don't have a pencil now)

You mean $$\operatorname{Hom}X(T,\operatorname{Spec}B ) \cong \operatorname{Hom}{A-alg}(B, \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}T)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}{\mathcal{O}{X}-Alg}(\tilde{B},f{*}(\mathcal{O}_T))$$ ?
If so, why the second isomorphism is true? I don't know how can we prove this rigorously. I am not sure exactly what is intention of your sentence..

I was thinking about it, and maybe one way is using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696265/morphism-of-sheaves-given-morphism-of-sheaves-on-a-base

Since for distinguished open sets, the maps from $B_f$ as $A_f$-algebra map is uniquely determined (when map from $B$ is given).

O.K. Q.1. Let $\psi : B \to \Gamma(T, \mathcal{O}T)$ be an $A$-algebra map. Let $g\in A$. Then there is an natural induced ( $A_g$-algebra? ) map $\psi_g : B_g \to \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}T){f^b{X}(g)} $, where $f^b : \mathcal{O}X \to f{*}\mathcal{O}_T$ ?

If so, then by composing with $\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}T){f^b_{X}(g)} \to \Gamma( T_{f^b_{X}(g)} ,\mathcal{O}_T)  = \Gamma ( f^{-1}(D_A(g)),\mathcal{O}T)$ ( $\because $ C.f. Gortz's ( 7.10.1 ), p.187, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572320/inverse-image-of-basic-open-set ), we have $A_g$ -algebra homomorphisms $B_g=\tilde{B}(D(g)) \to f{*}(\mathcal{O}_T) (D(g))$ for each $g\in A$.

Q.2. These homomorphisms really forms a morphism of sheaves on the base ( distinguished open sets ) ? Then by the Ravi Vakil, 2.5 C. exercise ( p.88 ) as you commented, there is uniquely determinded $\mathcal{O}X$-algebra homomorphism $ \eta{\psi} : \tilde{B} \to f_{*}(\mathcal{O}_T)$.
Q.3. This correspondence $\psi \mapsto \eta_{\psi}$ is bijective? Then we are done. Can you explain these stuff more friendly, possibly if you have time as a form of answer ?
